# existence and uniqueness of the index isomorphism

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $x_0 ∈ \Bbb C$ and $ S = \Bbb C \setminus \{x_0 \}$

$\forall x ∈ S$, prove existence and uniqueness of an isomorphism $ψ_{x_0, x} : π_1 (S, x) → \Bbb Z$ such that $ψ_{x_0 ,x} (α) = 1$, where $α$ is the homotopy class  of the loop $κ : I → S$, based on $x$, defined by
$t → x_0 + |x − x_0 | exp(i(2πt + arg(x − x_0 )))$

Some thoughts:

The problem is a mix between the index of a loop and the degree of an application that don't really understand.

$κ$ is a circle centered at $x_0$ with radius $|x-x_0|$ and $S$ has the same homotopy type as $κ$. so up to a translation from $0$ to $x_0$, there is a unique isomorphism  $π_1 (S, x) \to \Bbb Z$ associating the homotopy class of $S$ to the degree of  $α$.

Is the translation a valid argument to use the lifting of the exponential and reuse the degree application to define the index? If yes how to do it properly?

Thank you for any help and comments.

Comment: When you said unicity, did you mean uniqueness?

Comment: exactly! sorry my english is not perfect. I fixed that.